# Change SQLITE_LIMIT_SQL_LENGTH for inserting large items at the same time - Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I've had difficult to set new limit for sql length in the sqlite (version 3.10.2). I read the sql documentation and I noticed there is a function that allows to change the limit:  sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_SQL_LENGTH,size)

However, this function is for C interface.

I'd like to know if there is a function can i use in sql to change the sql length because I'll work with large sql statements.

Did anyone get this problem?

Thank you very much.

Carlos

Comment: Note from the [SQLite Limits](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) documentation:  *If an SQL statement is limited to be a million bytes in length, then obviously you will not be able to insert multi-million byte strings by embedding them as literals inside of INSERT statements. But you should not do that anyway. Use host parameters for your data. ... The use of binding obviates the need to escape quote characters in the string, reducing the risk of SQL injection attacks. It is also runs faster since the large string does not need to be parsed or copied as much.*

Comment: Why are your statements so large? This indicates that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SQL function for that.
And the [sqlite3_limit() function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/limit.html) allows to *reduce* the connection's limits, but not to increase them.

To *increase* the maximum length of an SQL statement, you would have to recompile the SQLite library with different [compilation options](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html).